# Update dict of dict value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have copied `B_cells` value into `A` dictionary. I am trying to add new element `A_cell` but it's impacting `B_cells` also

```
props = {'A_cells': {'t4drc_3': ['Path'],
            'tb4drc_1': ['Path']},

 'B_cells': {'t4drc_3': ['Path'],
             'tb4drc_1': ['Path']}
         }



props_dict['A_cells'] = props_dict['B_cell'].copy()


#Need to append data for A cells only
def append_in_dict_by_option(self, option, data):
        """Adding data in dictionary"""
        for key in props_dict[option].keys():
            self.props_dict[option][key].append(data)
```

So I was expecting output in `A_cells` only but it's impacting `B_cells`. Any idea

```
{'A_cells': {'t4drc_3': ['Path', data],
                'tb4drc_1': ['Path', data]},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because dict.copy returns a shallow copy of the dict. This means you get a new dict instance, but the elements in the dict are the same.

```
props['A_cells'] is props['B_cells'] #returns False
props['A_cells']['tb4drc_1'] is props['B_cells']['tb4drc_1'] #returns True
```

Therefore, if you append a value to props['A_cells']['tb4drc_1'], the change will be reflected in props['B_cells']['tb4drc_1'] - they contain the same list instance after all.

UPDATE:

To fix this, change

```
props_dict['A_cells'] = props_dict['B_cells'].copy()
```

to

```
from copy import deepcopy
props_dict['A_cells'] = deepcopy(props_dict['B_cells'])
```

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry for not including the fix in the first place.

Comment: Thx for providing input